# How to cover catch blocks?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to have a full code coverage of my method `writeList()`, but I don't know how to cover catch blocks.

My method is :

```
public class ListOfNumbers {


    //...another code...


    public void writeList() {
        try (FileOutputStream inputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.pathOut);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(inputStream);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numbers.size(); i++) {
                out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + this.numbers.get(i));
            }
        } catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage(),
                    e);
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "cover" with what? and why? be clear please.

Comment: First of all, why do you catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? it is a terrible practice in general to catch `RuntimeException` like this one, it denotes a design issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do unit test for Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305453/how-to-do-unit-test-for-exceptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it, If I were you, I would rewrite my code to make it more testable by moving the code that write the `numbers` into a different method, in order to mock this new method to make it throw whatever you want using [Mockito](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html).

So your code could be something like that:

```
public void writeList() {
    try (FileOutputStream inputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.pathOut);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(inputStream);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter)) {
        // Delegate the way to write the numbers to this new method
        writeNumbers(out);
    } catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error(
            "Caught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage(), e
        );
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
        ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

/**
 * The new method that is protected here but could also be package protected
 * but cannot be private to be able to override it.
 */
protected void writeNumbers(PrintWriter out) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numbers.size(); i++) {
        out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + this.numbers.get(i));
    }
}
```

Then your unit test could be:

```
@Test
public void causeAIOException() {
    ListOfNumbers lon = // Create your instance here
    // Create a Spy to be able to mock the method writeNumbers
    ListOfNumbers listOfNumbers = Mockito.spy(lon);
    // This will make any call to writeNumbers throw a IOException
    Mockito.doThrow(IOException.class).when(listOfNumbers)
        .writeNumbers(Matchers.any(PrintWriter.class));
    // Call the method on the spy
    listOfNumbers.writeList();
}
```

**NB:** In case of `FileNotFoundException`, you could simply provide an existing folder as `pathOut` as it is one of the cases for which `new FileOutputStream` will throw a `FileNotFoundException` and it is easy to reproduce.

Answer (score -1):

```
  class ListOfNumbers {

    public void writeList() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,FileNotFoundException,IOException  {
        try (FileOutputStream inputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.pathOut);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(inputStream);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.numbers.size(); i++) {
                out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + this.numbers.get(i));
            }

    }

}


public class Main{
 public static void main(String [] args){
   try{
    ListOfNumbers list=new ListOfNumbers();
try{
    list.writeList();
}
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage(),
                    e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ListOfNumbers.LOGGER.error("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }      

}
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you consider updating your answer to explain what you did here? Code only answers tend to be less helpful for others.

Comment: Well and re-check your code .. it can't compile due to several issues.